# Why do these form a basis for $\mathbb C^{n+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $\mathbb P_n$ be the complex projective space on $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, i.e. $$\mathbb P_n = \{[x_0,\ldots, x_n]: (x_0,\ldots, x_n) \in \Bbb C^{n+1} -\{0\} \}$$

where $[x_0,\ldots, x_n]$ is the equivalence class of $(x_0,\ldots, x_n)$ under the equivalence relation $\mathbb C^{n+1} \ni x \equiv y \in \Bbb C^{n+1} \iff \exists$ $\lambda \neq 0$: $x = \lambda y$.

Let $\pi$ be the projection map $\mathbb C^{n+1} -\{0\} \to \mathbb P_n$, $\pi(x_0,\ldots,x_n) = [x_0,\ldots,x_n]$. A hyperplane in $\mathbb P_n$ is $\pi(V-\{0\})$ where $V \subset \Bbb C^{n+1}$ is a subspace of dimension $n$.

Let $p_0,\ldots,p_n \in \mathbb P_n$ and suppose that they do not lie on a hyperplane. Let $u_0,\ldots, u_n \in \mathbb C^{n+1}$ such that $\pi(u_i) = p_i$.

Supposedly $\{u_0, \ldots, u_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. Why?

I am stuck at this. It is part of a proof in Kirwan's Complex Algebraic Curves p: 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the contrary, that $u_0, \dots, u_n$ do not form a basis of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Since they are $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ they must be linearly dependent, hence they belong to a $n$-dimensional subspace and their projection belong to a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Being linearly dependent, there are complex numbers $a_0, \dots , a_n$, not all zero, such that 
$$
a_0u_0 + \dots + a_nu_n =0 
$$
and writing the $u_j$s in coordinates will give you the equation of the hyperplane.

Comment: It feels quite frustrating I could not manage this one. So basic. But it has been a long time since I have done any math, so I guess it's kinda fair. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel bad about your doubts. The important thing is to solve them. No need to justify either ;)